# Proxy servers from a .net developers perspective

Tags: .net, proxy

I was wondering if anyone can recommend a good book / web site / blog or article (anything!) that can help demystify the proxy, not in terms of its use as a product, but purely from a .net developers point of view.

I know that in SOA systems, somewhere along the line you're bound to bump into a proxy, and this (in my experience) usually causes a deployment headache. Infact I've never really seen proxies as useful (but that's just me).

There are a couple of things that are specifically bothering me:

1. There is a proxy management system in IE, but I can't seem to figure out to what degree these IE settings impact on the server's connectivity as a whole. IE should in an ideal world just be a browser, yet it seems IE settings can effect the connectivity of the whole machine.
2. I cant seem to bypass proxy on local addresses using code. For example the following code just doesn't work:

   proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true; // Where proxy = System.Net.WebProxy

Would be nice if someone has written a proxy walk through because it seems there is a lot of confusion on the subject of poxies, I mean proxies.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think `WebProxy` just changes the settings for one connection, maybe you need to use `GlobalProxySelection` which should change it for the whole application?

The following two blog posts looks quite promising:

http://huddledmasses.org/setting-windows-internet-connection-proxy-from-c/

http://sturla.simnet.is/post/2008/09/22/Enable-proxy-in-IE.aspx

Comment: +1 - great links, thank you ho1. This is first piece of the puzzle.